# How to install express.js in directory where there is a template angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a ready template created with angular.js, it is divided into views, how do I install this directory express, which folders to merge? and how to make that template files do not get lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it in whatever manner you want, but i would suggest you to set up your server side stuffs first. Ensure it is working and then bring in the assets, Angular sources and libs.

To make your development faster, express provides [generators](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html), just run this command it will create default set of files for you. Off course you can change the folder structure to the one that suits best to your application.

Once Express it working fine, then embed the client side stuffs, recommended would be to keep it in a separate directory. Most people like to keep folder names **client**(for client side scripts) and **server**(for server related scripts).

Most new single page applications are being developed in MEAN stack(Mongo, ExpressJS, AngularJS, MongoDB). There are some interesting seed projects such as [MEAN.io](http://mean.io) and [MEAN.js](http://meanjs.org), which i think would be helpful for you in order to setup the project and quickly get started.

Also do checkout [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) and [bower](http://bower.io).
**Grunt** is javascript task runner which can help you automate many of your tedious tasks.